# When I create a 9 patch image for splash screens, it comes out way too small for larger devices

Tags: android, splash-screen, nine-patch

I've decided to use a 9 patch image for my splash screens.
The problem is, on larger devices, that the Splash Image is way too small, and I want my splash to take up the majority of the screen.

On smaller devices it is fine.
I don't think I am creating these 9 patch Images the correct way.

**Can somebody point me to a some site, or GitHub repository that uses a 9 patch splash screen image that takes up most of the screen size on all devices?**

I want to put this in my app and see what I'm doing wrong.

SplashTheme.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" > //This is so I can have a white background
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/splash" 
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="center"
    />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: 9 patches are images (PNGs, to be precise). Therefore, they follow the density-bucket rule which is valid for **every** image (with no exception): create several versions of your 9 patch.

Comment: Please post your layout file that includes the 9patch in question.

Comment: I have several versions of the image all in their respective folders. Just looking for somebody else's example of one that takes up the entire screen on each device

Comment: Thank you for including the 9patch. But could you inclulde the layout file? The one that sits in the layout directory and is inflated in your activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This

```
<item>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/splash" 
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="center"
    />
</item>
```

must be changed to

```
<item>
    <nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:src="@drawable/splash" 
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="center"
    />
</item>
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch

Comment: Thanks for this! However, I still cannot get my images to stretch the right way...Now they are way overblown. I'm still looking for some example of nine-patch that takes up the entire screen just so I can test it out.

Comment: If your 9 patch is well designed, it will be stretched to fit its container. I edited my answer to add a link to a nice tutorial which says it all (and easy) on 9 patches.

Comment: @BobMalooga link is a 404,I have the same problem tough: my 9 patches png are created right, but they are rendered too small on tablets

Comment: As with phones (yes with phones too!), you should provide different drawables in different folders. **9 patches aren't meant to replace the density system** (for this, see VectorDrawables or - even better - SVG files). They are meant to be stretchable only inside their density bucket.

Comment: @BobMalooga I have one 9.png for each resolution Android requires: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi...

Comment: OK. But you don't have specific drawables for tablets, right? Then, it's likely that your tablet won't choose the graphics from the right bucket.